# Balloon Notification Error when using the TaskbarIcon Library for a WPF Project

Tags: wpf, non-static, balloon-tip

I'm trying to implement the a Balloon Notification to appear when a button is clicked however I keep receiving a specific error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
'TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(string, string, BalloonIcon)
```

I'm using the library `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification;`

The  Method is

```
class NotifyIcon
{
    public static void ShowStandardBalloon()
    {
        string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
        string text = "This is a standard balloon";
        TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

and is called:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyIcon ST = new NotifyIcon();
        ST.ShowStandardBalloon();
    }
```

Error is appearing under `TaskbarIcon.ShowBalloonTip`.

I've tried changing to `public static void` in the Notify Icon class however that didn't resolve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the ShowBalloonTip on and instance of TaskbarIcon

```
TaskbarIcon TBIcon = new TaskbarIcon()
string title = "WPF NotifyIcon";
string text = "This is a standard balloon";
TBIcon.ShowBalloonTip(title, text, BalloonIcon.Error);
```